# When the user clicks an element: Prevent default action, present menu(s), then resume default action when menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

**Goal**

When the user clicks an element (with `class="menu"`), the default action should not be executed. The user should be presented with a menu with options. When an option has been clicked, then the default action should be executed.

**Problem**

It's very problematic to stop the original click event in the first place, because it seems impossible to restore "default behavior" after that - is there a way to just delay the event until the user clicks a menu item?

**Example**

What i want to happen: Click a link. A menu is appended to the body. Click a menu option. The default behavior for the original click is now executed (which means triggering the click event of the originally clicked link and redirection to example.com).

**jsFiddle**

HTML, JS and CSS here:
http://jsfiddle.net/arex1337/Tjwmx/

PS: If you want to know what I need the functionality for, here are some hastily and badly written thoughts about the application I have in mind: www. scribd.com /doc/39573220/MyJsApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible; you'll need to simulate the default behavior in code.

You can set `location.href` to the link's `href`.

Comment: 1. Why isn't this possible? It's certainly possible to do SOME stuff before you let the original click event happen.
2. Your solution doesn't trigger the native click event which may trigger other stuff.
3. I would rather not try to simulate behavior and trigger all the proper events for each type of element. Link = native click + follow href. Text field = native click + focus. And on and on. To let the original event through is much better.

Comment: @arex: 1: It just isn't.  You can't cause the click handler to block without freezing the entire browser.  2. I realize that.  You can raise the event using jQuery.  3. You'll need to write a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily, take a look at this:
[Quick modification of code from question](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNJYmv)

```
// create container for url of clicked link 
var event_href = {};

function createMenu(options) {
    $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
    $ul.append('<li class="menu-header">'+options.header+'</li>');
    for (var $i = 0; $i < options.choices.length; $i++) {
        $ul.append('<li class="menu-item">'+options.choices[$i]+'</li>');
    }
    return $ul;
}

function resumeClick(){
    window.location.href = event_href;
}

$('.menu').click('click', function(e) {
    // save event data
    event_href = e.currentTarget.href;
    e.preventDefault()
        $('#placeholder ul').remove();
    createMenu({
        header: 'Choose something',
        choices: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
    }).appendTo('#placeholder');
    // init listeners on menu items with callbacks == resume function
    $('.menu-item').click('click', function(){
    resumeClick();})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="example.com" class="menu">Click me!</a>
```

CSS:

```
.menu { background: red; color: white; }
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].addEventListener('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Element clicked: ' + e.target.tagName + '')); }, false);
```

The above will log the element that was clicked without triggering the link, and then you can do whatever you want with it.